# Convert enum values to strings

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code snippet:

```
enum class Code : uint8_t
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2
};
```

How can I add a conversion operator (or something similar if possible) to the enum such that when I pass enum object to the function which accepts `std::string`, the objects will be **implicitly** converted to `std::string`.
The aim is to convert `0` to string `"0"`, `1` to `"1"` etc.

> Note: I don't want to add function like, e.g., `toString`,
> because I need **implicit conversion**.

Comment: Best you can do is replacing the enum with a class that pretends to be one, and adding a conversion operator to it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The issue is that the enum types are being passed later to some shared/generic functions, like `FromEnum` which does the following:
`static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<Enum>::type>(enumValue);`
So, I guess, I am not allowed to change enum to class.
Why it is not possible to define conversion operator to `std::string` for enum type.

Comment: @DavidHovsepyan your comment above brings important context to the question. Could you add an example of intended usage to your post?

Comment: Because the language doesn't have this feature. If you can't replace the enum with a class, then you need to wrap `std::string` in your own class (or just abandon this idea, given that implicit conversions are starting to be viewed as a bad thing those days).

Comment: You can't add conversion operator to a enum, period. Your options are: 1. replacing enum with a class, 2. replacing `std::string` parameter with a wrapper class that can accept a enum (or something else), 3. not doing implicit conversions at all.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 2nd option suits me the best in my scenario, but I don't understand what do you mean by "replacing std::string parameter with a wrapper class...". Can you please provide a simple/short example (if possible)?

Comment: I mean a class with a `std::string` member, with two constructors: one taking a string, and another taking your enum and converting it to a string.

Comment: "I need implicit conversion" Please reconsider this. Implicit conversions are syntactic sugar we all can go without, as they often cause hard-to-find bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I originally posted an example of how to achieve this using some implicit conversion tricks, but realised this could be simplified a bit further.

I'll assume you wrote the method you are wanting to pass your `Code` type to; the simplest option would then be to add in a simple overload which also accepts a `Code`, performs the translation to `std::string`, and then passes the result to the other method, e.g.

```cpp
void work(std::string);

/* adding.... */
void work(Code c)
{
  switch (c)
  {
    case Code::A: return work("A");
    case Code::B: return work("B");
    case Code::C: return work("C");
    default: __builtin_unreachable();
  }
}
```

If the method in particular is part of the standard library, I believe adding your own overload here would be UB, however you could introduce it in a new namespace and use ADL to figure the rest out.

The best answer will ultimately depend on the exact situation you find yourself in, but this could be a good starting point.

Comment: Instead of `default:`, it's generally better to put the call to `std::unreachable();` _after_ the `switch`, so we don't lose the compiler check that all values are accounted for.

Comment: @TobySpeight Question mentions tag C++ 11, [std::unreachable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/unreachable) is from C++ 23.

Comment: Correct, but the comment is more that a default branch shouldn't be included here, and the `__builtin_unreachable` call should be outside of the switch for the purpose of better warnings

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly *why* you need this, so my suggestion might be wide of the mark.  But if you need a value that can be treated as *either* a `Code` or a string, then we can create a wrapper class that will convert to either of these:

```
struct Code_class
{
    Code c;

    Code_class(Code c) : c{c} {}

    operator Code() const
    {
        return c;
    }

#define X(x) case Code::x: return #x
    operator std::string() const
    {
        switch (c) {
            X(A);
            X(B);
            X(C);
        }
        std::unreachable();
    }
#undef X
};
```

---

### Full demo

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

enum class Code : uint8_t
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2
};

struct Code_class
{
    Code c;

    /* implicit */ Code_class(Code c) : c{c} {}

    operator Code() const
    {
        return c;
    }

#define X(x) case Code::x: return #x
    operator std::string() const
    {
        switch (c) {
            X(A);
            X(B);
            X(C);
        }
        std::unreachable();
    }
#undef X
};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    auto m = Code::A;

    Code_class p = m;
    const std::string s = p;

    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I was writing answer in a similar spirit ;) But then I realized the boilerplate code might become somewhat large to maintain: additional assignments from enum, comparisons etc.

Comment: Interesting how we all converged on the same ideas originally! The main downside here is that there is still an explicit step required to perform this conversion, as the original `Code` type cannot be passed to a method accepting a `std::string` without explicitly naming the `Code_class` constructor here, which is tantamount to having a method like `toString` which the OP was aiming to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

char is a kind of integer so we could declare enum of char.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

enum struct Cnum : char { h = 'h', o = 'o', e = 'e', l = 'l' , num_0 = '0' };

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Cnum c) {
    os << static_cast<char>(c);
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Cnum::h << Cnum::e << Cnum::l << Cnum::l << Cnum::o << Cnum::num_0 << "\n";//print hello0
}
```

then you could build string from char later.

Comment: My assumption is that OP wants a general purpose solution that would work even for members with more complex names. Further, the enum value may need to be 0 in value, but have a different string representation.